# React-Redux not updating value on SetInterval

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

On a custom component, if I dispatch a new value by `onPress` function it works. If I set it into a `setInterval` or `Background-Timer`, the new value is not updated.

Reducer:

```
import initialState from './InitialState';

export function setData(type, data) {
    if (!data) var data = '';
    return {
        type: type,
        state: data
    }
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("action che arriva al reducer", action)

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'setInitialState':
            return initialState
        case 'setTipology':
            return {
                ...state, typology: action.state
            }
            case 'setTimer':
                return {
                    ...state, timer: action.state
                }
    }

    return state;
}

export default reducer
```

Custom Component :

```
const Timer = ({
    title,
    action
}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const reduxState = useSelector(state => state)

    const timerFunction = (action) => {
        if (action == "start") {
            //dispatch(setData('setTimer', reduxState.timer  + 1000))
            BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => {
                dispatch(setData('setTimer', reduxState.timer + 1000))
            }, 1000);

        } else if (action == "end") {
            return BackgroundTimer.stopBackgroundTimer(); //after this call all code on background stop run.
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => timerFunction(action)}
                style={styles.cButton}
            >
                <Text style={styles.testo}>{title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </>
    )
}
```

If I use ONLY the commented line it works:

```
( dispatch(setData('setTimer', reduxState.timer  + 1000)) )
```

In this example didn't work.
Any suggestions?